# How to skip a directory when I am setting up permissions using find?

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I have a directory `/sources` and inside it's the `.idea` directory which belongs to phpStorm projects. The directory `/sources` is mounted as a `VOLUME` in a Docker container (`~/sources:/var/www`). I have a script running at container start which is setting up some permissions as follow:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/sources && find /var/www/sources -type d -print0 | xargs -0
chmod 2775 && find /var/www/sources -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0664
```

And those permissions goes also to `.idea` which is making phpStorm not to have access to the folder and therefore is not able to write there.

> Could not save project: Unable to save project files. Please ensure
>   project files are writable and you have permissions to modify them.

I have read some posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065447/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-when-performing-file-operations-i-e-cp-mv-rm-and-ch
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163294/changing-chmod-for-files-but-not-directories

But the solution is slight different from mine. How do I skip the `.idea` directory using the statement above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the directory `/var/www/sources/.idea` and everything in it:

```
find /var/www/sources -type d -not -path '/var/www/sources/.idea*' -exec chmod 0755 {} +
find /var/www/sources -type f -not -path '/var/www/sources/.idea*' -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```